# Grouping Json by related value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

This JSON comes in as an order with multiple products related by vendorId. I want to be able to group this to an independent array set instead of having all listed as one long set of products. How can I achieve this?

My Code

```js
    let order =     {
        "products": [
            {
                "_id": "5e989346731e4d11c4a06331",
                "productId": "5e9ee6ad8ac51f4654846552",
                "vendorId": "5e8547fb14033339a86cc349",
                "name": "Laterral",
                "price": 1000,
                "count": 2

            },
            {
                "_id": "5e990589823c501e640be183",
                "productId": "5e989346731e4d11c4a06331",
                "vendorId": "5e8547fb14033339a86cc349",
                "name": "ANother Product",
                "price": 12453,
                "count": 3

            },
            {
                "_id": "5e9ee6ad8ac51f4654846552",
                "productId": "5e989346731e4d11c4a06331",
                "vendorId": "5e8547fb14033339a86cc309",
                "name": "ANother Product",
                "price": 12453,
                "count": 3
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e9904c3cd559006fc2b92b3",
                "productId": "5e989346731e4d11c4a06331",
                "vendorId": "5e8547fb14033339a86cc309",
                "name": "ANother Product",
                "price": 12453,
                "count": 3
            }
        ],
        "address":"Colonel 10",
        "amount":"234555",
        "transaction_id":"3334hdd",
        "status":"Not processed"
    }

    let products = order.products
    //console.log(products)
     arr = []
    products.map(product => {
      vendorId = product.vendorId
      price = product.price
      quantity = product.count
      productId = product.productId

      if(vendorId == product.vendorId) {
        arr.vendorId = vendorId
        arr.productId = productId
        arr.price = price
        arr.count = quantity
        arr.total = price * quantity; //arr.reduce((cum, xtr) => cum + xtr.price * xtr.count,0)
        tem = "========= \n " +arr.count+" Products ordered from this vendor " + vendorId + "\n"  + arr.productId +" for "+ arr.price + " Total of " + arr.total;

      }

      console.log(arr)
    })

This is my output

    [
      vendorId: '5e8547fb14033339a86cc349',
      productId: '5e9ee6ad8ac51f4654846552',
      price: 1000,
      count: 2,
      total: 2000
    ]
    [
      vendorId: '5e8547fb14033339a86cc349',
      productId: '5e989346731e4d11c4a06331',
      price: 12453,
      count: 3,
      total: 37359
    ]
    [
      vendorId: '5e8547fb14033339a86cc309',
      productId: '5e989346731e4d11c4a06331',
      price: 12453,
      count: 3,
      total: 37359
    ]
    [
      vendorId: '5e8547fb14033339a86cc309',
      productId: '5e989346731e4d11c4a06331',
      price: 12453,
      count: 3,
      total: 37359
    ]

This is my intended output

    "order":{
   "vendor":[
      {
         "productId":"5e9ee6ad8ac51f4654846552",
         "price":1000,
         "count":2,
         "total":2000
      },
      {
         "productId":"5e989346731e4d11c4a06331",
         "price":12453,
         "count":3,
         "total":37359
      }
   ],
   "vendorId":"5e8547fb14033339a86cc349",
   "gtotal":39359,
"vendor":[
   {
      "productId":"5e989346731e4d11c4a06331",
      "price":12453,
      "count":3,
      "total":37359
   },
   {
      "productId":"5e989346731e4d11c4a06331",
      "price":12453,
      "count":3,
      "total":37359
   }
],
"vendorId":"5e8547fb14033339a86cc309",
"gtotal":‭74718‬
}
```

What's the best way for this.

Comment: I think your intended output is a wrong JSON code. Can you please double-check and update your answer so we can help you?

Comment: You need to validate your intended output with a validator e.g. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/. It's not valid JSON.

Comment: @Azeem - the output won't be JSON, it'll be a javascript object ... since the code in the question doesn't JSON.stringify the result, the result will never be JSON - lets face it, the INPUT isn't even JSON ... it's just an object

Comment: I can handle but output in either JSON or object format.

Comment: @YabaCoder can you please format your question?

Comment: Your intended output is **still not valid** ... `{vendor: [array of products], vendorId: 'some id' ...etc}` is not valid you'd need something like `{vendor: { products:[array of products], vendorId: 'some id' ...etc}}`

Comment: I can't understand your intended output, also it is invalid JSON.

Comment: Example:
Order Basket
product A Sold by Vendor 1
Product B Sold by Vendor 1
Product C Sold by Vendor 3
Product D Sold by Vendor 2
Product E Sold by Vendor 2

The output should be
SubOrder 1
**Vendor 1**
Product A
Product B

SubOrder 2
**Vendor 3**
Product C

SubOrder 3
**Vendor 2**
Product D
Product E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't produce your required output, since your required output is completely invalid

But this comes close to what I think you want

```js
let order={"products":[{"_id":"5e989346731e4d11c4a06331","productId":"5e9ee6ad8ac51f4654846552","vendorId":"5e8547fb14033339a86cc349","name":"Laterral","price":1000,"count":2},{"_id":"5e990589823c501e640be183","productId":"5e989346731e4d11c4a06331","vendorId":"5e8547fb14033339a86cc349","name":"ANother Product","price":12453,"count":3},{"_id":"5e9ee6ad8ac51f4654846552","productId":"5e989346731e4d11c4a06331","vendorId":"5e8547fb14033339a86cc309","name":"ANother Product","price":12453,"count":3},{"_id":"5e9904c3cd559006fc2b92b3","productId":"5e989346731e4d11c4a06331","vendorId":"5e8547fb14033339a86cc309","name":"ANother Product","price":12453,"count":3}],"address":"Colonel 10","amount":"234555","transaction_id":"3334hdd","status":"Not processed"};
const products = order.products;


const vendor = products.reduce((acc, {productId, price, count, vendorId}) => {
    let total = price * count;
    let existing_vendor = acc.find(i => i.vendorId === vendorId);
    if (!existing_vendor) {
        acc.push({products:[{productId, price, count, total}], vendorId, gtotal:total});
    } else {
        existing_vendor.products.push({productId, price, count, total});
        existing_vendor.gtotal += total;
    }
    return acc
}, []);

const result = {order: {vendor}};
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey @Jaromanda, by mistake I have edited your response and submitted. Apologies for not looking into what I'm editing before the submission.

Comment: Thanks, this captures my expectation.

Comment: All good @NithishGandesiri - doesn't look like your suggested edit was approved

Answer (score 0):

As per what I understood from your question and the required output json, I felt this might fit the output json structure which you are be expecting

```js
const orders = {
        "products": [
            {
                "_id": "5e989346731e4d11c4a06331",
                "productId": "5e9ee6ad8ac51f4654846552",
                "vendorId": "5e8547fb14033339a86cc349",
                "name": "Laterral",
                "price": 1000,
                "count": 2

            },
            {
                "_id": "5e990589823c501e640be183",
                "productId": "5e989346731e4d11c4a06331",
                "vendorId": "5e8547fb14033339a86cc349",
                "name": "ANother Product",
                "price": 12453,
                "count": 3

            },
            {
                "_id": "5e9ee6ad8ac51f4654846552",
                "productId": "5e989346731e4d11c4a06331",
                "vendorId": "5e8547fb14033339a86cc309",
                "name": "ANother Product",
                "price": 12453,
                "count": 3
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e9904c3cd559006fc2b92b3",
                "productId": "5e989346731e4d11c4a06331",
                "vendorId": "5e8547fb14033339a86cc309",
                "name": "ANother Product",
                "price": 12453,
                "count": 3
            }
        ],
        "address":"Colonel 10",
        "amount":"234555",
        "transaction_id":"3334hdd",
        "status":"Not processed"
    }

const formattedProducts = orders.products.reduce((result, product) => {
  const vendorObj = result.find(r => r.vendor.vendorId === product.vendorId);
  if(vendorObj) {
    vendorObj.vendor.products.push(product);
    vendorObj.vendor.total += product.price
  } else {
    result.push({"vendor": {products: [product], vendorId: product.vendorId, total: product.price}})
  }

return result
}, [])

const result = {orders:[...formattedProducts]}

console.log(result)
```

In the final output, inside the vendor array each product is having the same info as in the input. If all the values are not need, they can be removed. But just for the sake of keeping them there I have not deleted or not added only those you are looking for.